# How to get around the fact C# doesn't allow void as a generic parameter? 

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following generic classes, which handle requests that return different kinds of objects:

```
class Request<T> {
    /* ... */

    public T Result { get; protected set; }
    public abstract bool Execute();
    protected bool ExecuteCore(params /* ... */) { /* ... */ }
}

class ObjectRequest<T> : Request<T>
    where T : class, new() { /* ... */ }

class ListRequest<T> : Request<List<T>>
    where T : class, new() { /* ... */ }

class CompoundRequest<T, U> : Request<T>
    where T : class, IHeader<U>, new()
    where U : class, new() { /* ... */ }

class CompoundRequest<T, U, V> : Request<T>
    where T : class, IHeader<U>, IHeader<V>, IHeader<W>, new()
    where U : class, new()
    where V : class, new() { /* ... */ }

class CompoundRequest<T, U, V, W> : Request<T>
    where T : class, IHeader<U>, IHeader<V>, new()
    where U : class, new()
    where V : class, new()
    where W : class, new() { /* ... */ }

interface IHeader<T> {
    List<T> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to create a class that handles requests that return *no* objects. However, setting a generic parameter to null is not allowed:

```
class NoReturnRequest : Request<void> { /* ... */ } // illegal
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend flipping your design pattern around; first you should build a non-generic `Request` class that doesn't return anything, and **from** it inherit generic `Request<T>`, `Request<T1, T2>`, `Request<T1, T2, T3>`, etc.. classes that do return values.

Comment: @Adam: This breaks the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: @Eduardo I have to respectfully disagree. What makes you think this?

Comment: @Adam: It doesn't follow from my question, but it follows from the way my classes would be implemented if I follow your approach. Either it breaks the LSP, or there is some functionality that needs to be implemented twice.

Comment: @Eduardo Again, I have to disagree. While I certainly won't claim to know the internal details of your `Request` and related classes, I'm not sure why you can't implement the details of submitting the request in the non-generic request class, and the details of acquiring the return value(s) in the generic derived classes. Especially if you add some virtual functions in the base class to allow the derived classes to easily tie into the already-provided functionality.

Comment: @Adam: Sorry, I do not understand what you said. According to your proposal, there would be _two_ base classes. `Request` would be the base of `Request<T>`, which would in turn be the base of `ObjectRequest<T>`, `ListRequest<T>`, `CompoundRequest<T,U>`, `CompoundRequest<T,U,V>` and `CompoundRequest<T,U,V,W>`. Which base class are you talking about?

Comment: @Eduardo for the scope of this design change, I'm only talking about `Request` and `Request<T>`. I don't know about your architecture, but I would assume that the different types of requests you've specified are just some added functionality atop those base classes. So, the base class I was referring to would be `Request`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem as languages such as C# become more functionally-oriented.

The Rx team solved it by introducing [Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.unit%28v=VS.103%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Generics are used for a typed parameters. If the parameter does not have type, use interface or abstract from another class (which your Request will also inherit from)